# Get all relationships in many-to-many polymorphic

Tags: php, laravel

I know that many-to-many polymorphic relationship is possible. However, the tutorials points me in a way that each tables will be in a separate relationship (function).

However, I need a way to create a many-to-many polymorphic relationship wherein I can fetch all of its relationships even if they're from multiple tables.

Example:

```
Log
->connected_tables (the model relationship)
--> [0] App\User
--> [1] App\User
--> [2] App\Transaction
--> [3] App\Item
--> [4] App\ShippingInformation
```

The pivot table is as follows:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('entity_id')->unsigned();
$table->string('entity_type');
$table->integer('loggable_id')->unsigned();
$table->string('loggable_type');
```

Then in my log model, I'm trying to fetch it as:

```
public function loggable()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\????', 'entity', 'activity_log_entity');
}
```

This is the part where I don't know what to put anymore.

Comment: show the queries how you are trying to get

Comment: The many-to-many relationship uses morphToMany. But it requires the first parameter which is a model, but the model(s) could be different in one result.

return $this->morphToMany('App\????', 'entity', 'activity_log_entity');

Comment: You can simply use `YourModel::with(' your relation ')->get()`

Comment: That will only get one kind of model. I want to fetch multiple models in one relationship.

The supposed relationship will be all the rows affected from a certain action. So it could be 1 or more tables.

Comment: Can you post your model?

Comment: I updated to post along with my model's only relationship.

Comment: The more I think about this the more I think it's not possible to do this. Maybe you can just get each morphed relationship and just merge the result collections

Comment: That's my last resort. But it's too much hassle. All the 70+ tables could be in the relationship. There's no way I'm gonna do that manually.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a work-around this problem. But I've got a small problem along with it.

First, in my log table, I put a hasMany relationship through my pivot and eagerloaded the "relatedTables"

```
public function logs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\LogPivot', 'entity_id')->with('relatedTables');
}
```

Then I created a model for the pivot and put this relationship

```
public function relatedTables()
{
    return $this->morphTo('loggable');
}
```

So this will fetch all of the pivots of a log, then each pivots will morph themselves into whatever they are pointed to.

The problem is that the pivot will be the first instead of the actual table. How can I "pluck" the actual table instead of the pivot?

```
App\LogPivot {#1251
  id: 2,
  entity_id: 573,
  entity_type: "log",
  loggable_id: 3,
  loggable_type: "user",
  created_at: null,
  updated_at: null,
  related_table: null,
  loggable: App\User {#1259
    id: 3,
    name: "Juan",
  },
},
```

I want to get the App\User straight on its relationship instead of LogPivot first

Comment: What do you think about `->pluck('loggable')`? Will not improve performance, but this is something :D

Answer (score 1):

We can easily retrieve all the models in a relationship by creating a model for the pivot table. As example,

This is the example for many to many polymorphic relationship in [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations).

```
posts
    id - integer
    name - string

videos
    id - integer
    name - string

tags
    id - integer
    name - string

taggables
    tag_id - integer
    taggable_id - integer
    taggable_type - string
```

We can create models '`App\Post`','`App\Video`','`App\Tag`' and '`App\Taggable`'.
To retrieve all the models with a specific tag id we can use, "'`App\Taggable'::where('tag_id',1)->get()`".

Also for more ease, we can add the following function to the '`App\Tag`' model.

```
public function taggables()
{
    return 'App\Taggable'::where('tag_id',$this->id)->get();
}
```

Comment: What would the App\Taggable model look like in its entirety for clarity on this solution?

Comment: @SupaMonkey Just empty Laravel eloquent model. you don't need to add anything specific.